# How to call Rest API from Dialogflow

Tags: dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I want to call Rest API by querying DialogFlow.I am new to this any Help will be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! There are many questions here about calling REST APIs from Dialogflow - I suggest you search them and see if they help you. Also look at the documentation at https://docs.dialogflow.com/  If these don't help, see [How Do I Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for tips on how to ask a question that others on SO can help you answer. The more information you give us - the better our chance are of helping you. In particular, very open-ended questions don't get good results - show your code and what you've tried and what isn't working.

Comment: @user1727223 I am assuming you already have a dialogflow agent, and want to know how you could access all the information regarding your agent via dialogflow API calls.

Comment: Let's make it simple , I am having a Rest API for some third party services ,I want to trigger the rest API with dialogflow,is that possible

Answer (score 0):

On how to interact with the google cloud platform dialogflow APIs, check out this [Google Cloud Platform reference](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/quick/api#detect_intent). According to this [Google Cloud Platform reference](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/quick/api#detect_intent), you may use the API for interactions, so that your service interacts directly with the end-user. For each conversational turn, your service sends end-user expressions to Dialogflow by calling the detectIntent or streamingDetectIntent method of the Sessions type. Dialogflow responds with information about the matched intent, the action, the parameters, and the response defined for the intent. Your service performs actions as needed (for example, database queries or external API calls) and sends a message to the end-user. This process continues until the conversation has ended.

To authenticate calls to Google Cloud Platform APIs, readup this resource [Authentication overview](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/). This page provides an overview of authentication in Google Cloud Platform (GCP) for application developers. It describes principals, application credentials, and various ways to authenticate calls to GCP APIs.

I hope this helps?